# add systems test and unit tests to nextflow code

Tags: unit-testing, nextflow, system-testing

what are the ways and best practices to get a tool with systems test and unit tests that cover and valid a maximum of code?

I already have my tool (nextflow pipeline) but without those tests.

Should I restart the project completely and build a test per new file I will generate? Or can I adapt an existing project?

How to adapt those tests for such code? Any examples?

Comment: I don't have much experience myself, but I saw someone released `nf-test` for unit testing a while ago. Link [here](https://www.nf-test.com/).